# XSLT 2.0: Find missing elements in a sequence

Tags: xslt-2.0, saxon, xpath-2.0

I need to search for a range of elements based on ID numbers.  If the ID number is found, I'll process it.  If the ID is not found, it'll get filled in with a default value.  I'm using XSLT 2.0 in Saxon 9.4 HE.

Here's a very simplified example.  The input XML looks like this:

```
<root>
    <item>
        <id>1</id>
    </item>
    <item>
        <id>2</id>
    </item>
    <item>
        <id>4</id>
    </item>
</root>
```

If I'm searching for items whose ID is 1, 2, or 3, I'd like to get the following output.  Note that I don't want any output for item 4.

```
Found 1
Found 2
Didn't find 3
```

My first attempt was with a for-each loop but it doesn't even compile.  The error I get is "XPTY0020: Axis step child::element('':id) cannot be used here: the context item is an atomic value" from the line "".

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:variable name="ids" select="(1, 2, 3)"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:for-each select="$ids">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="count(item/id = .) > 0">
                Found <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                Didn't find <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

After that I realized I could easily find the matching ones with the following, but I can't puzzle out a way to find the missing ones.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:variable name="ids" select="(1, 2, 3)"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="root/item[id=$ids]"/>
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template match="item">
    Found <xsl:value-of select="id"/>
</xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

BTW, the output also needs to be sorted by ID, which means that dumping a list of all the items that were found, followed by a list of the ones that were not found won't work.  Is this even possible or should I take the easy/wimpy road and change my input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:key name="k1" match="item" use="number(id)"/>

<xsl:param name="ids" select="(1, 2, 3)"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="root" select="."/>
    <xsl:for-each select="$ids">
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="key('k1', ., $root)">
          <xsl:text>Found </xsl:text>
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:text>Didn't find </xsl:text>
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
      <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

[edit]
Your initial attempt was right as for as processing the sequence of ids is concerned, but you need to store the main input document outside of the for-each as inside the context item is an id number value and without the outer variable you wouldn't be able to access the item elements in the document.

And for efficiency, I added the key.

Comment: This did the trick and I was able to modify it to work with my real problem rather than my over-simplified example.  Also, thanks for the explanation of what was wrong with my first attempt.

Comment: You mentioned that the reason you used a key is for efficiency.  Just to further my XSLT knowledge, would you mind showing an example that does not use a key as well?

Answer (score 1):

**Here is a simpler (no explicit conditionals) and shorter solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:key name="kIdByVal" match="id" use="."/>

 <xsl:param name="psortedIds" as="xs:string+"
      select="'1','2','3'"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vDoc" select="/"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:for-each select="$psortedIds">
   <xsl:sequence select=
   '("found ", "didn&apos;t find ")
       [2 - number(boolean(key("kIdByVal", current(), $vDoc)))],
    ., "&#xA;"
   '/>
  </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this XSLT 2.0 transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<root>
    <item>
        <id>1</id>
    </item>
    <item>
        <id>2</id>
    </item>
    <item>
        <id>4</id>
    </item>
</root>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
found  1 
 found  2 
 didn't find  3
```

Comment: This works for the problem I presented, but unfortunately it seems that I over-simplified my example and I wasn't able to generalize this.  My apologies for leading you astray!

Comment: @donkey: Don't worry, you can always ask a new question. One also gradually learns how to ask good questions.